# RHEL internet connection behind company proxy?

Tags: rhel, proxy, internet

Just set up a RHEL v6.4 VDE for development but I can't seem to connect to the internet no matter what I try. I'm sitting behind a company proxy that requires authentication. Here's what I've done so far:

- Put the link to my company's `.pac` file under the Automatic Proxy Configuration option in Network Settings
- Put `export http_proxy=<company proxy>` and `export https_proxy=<company proxy>` in my `.bashrc` file
- Updated values for `proxy`, `proxy_username`, and `proxy_password` within the `yum.conf` file as well as `enableProxy`, `proxyPassword`, `proxyUser`, `httpProxy`, and `enableProxyAuth` within the `up2date` file

After each of these steps, I've tried connecting to the internet via Konqueror (as far as I know, no other browsers were packaged with the OS). I chose "Automatically detect proxy configuration" within the browser settings but each time I try there's no response.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a very specific problem, but if anyone happens to run into something similar in the future, here's what I did to resolve it: I installed Firefox through ZenWorks (turns out it was prepackaged with the OS) and I managed to get online right away from there. It immediately prompted me for my authentication credentials, which Konqueror did not. I'm sure there's a way to configure Konqueror in such a way that would allow this, but Firefox worked seamlessly, so I know I'll be sticking with that.